# What is the difference between state evaluation and heuristics in game-AI?

Tags: state, heuristics, minimax, game-ai

I am trying to implement a minimax algorithm for an AI player within a simple card game. However, from doing research I am confused what are the key differences between state evaluation and heuristics.

From what I understand heuristics are calculated by the current information available to the player (e.g. in chess, the pieces and their relevant locations). With this infomation, they come to a conclusion based on a heuristics function which essentially provides a "rule of thumb".

A state evaluation is the exact value of the current state.

However I am unsure why both things co-exist as I cannot see how they are much different from one another. Please can someone ellaborate, and clear up my confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a zero-sum game, you can implement a state-evaluation for end-states (game ended with win, draw, loss from perspective of player X) which results 1,0,-1. A full tree-search will then get you perfect-play.

But in practice the tree is huge and can't be searched completely. Therefore you have to stop the search at some point, which is not an end-state. There is no determined winner or loser. Now it's hard to mark this state with 1,0,-1 as the game might be too complex to easily evaluate the winner from some state far away from the end-state. But you still need to evaluate this positions and can use some assumptions about the game, which equals to heuristic-information. One example is piece-mass in chess (queen is more valuable then a pawn). This is heuristic information incorporated into the non-perfect evaluation-function (approximation of the real one). The better your assumptions / heuristics, the better the approximation of the real evaluation!

But there are other parts where heuristic information can be incorporated. One very imporant area is controlling the tree-search. Which first-move will be evaluated first, which last. Selecting good moves first allows algorithms like alpha-beta to prune huge parts of the tree. But of course you need to state some assumptions/ heuristic-information to order your moves (e.g. queen-move more powerful than pawn-move; this is a made-up example, i'm not sure about the effect of this heuristic in chess-AIs here)